# How to properly implement in-between model of ListIterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to write my own `CustomLinkedList<E>` to rapidly pass labs where I need to implement stacks and queues. I can pass the labs without this class (since I don't need to implement iterable at all), but I would like to grasp the concept since I'm learning java anyway.

I've got most of things running and tested now, but I couldn't make iterator to work properly yet.

The **first approach** was "post-increment", e.g.:

```
E result = current.getValue();
current = current.getNext();
return result;
```

which I found to be broken, because then when I reach the end of the list, I won't be able to get back. My `hasNext()` just checks if the current is `null`, thus the ability to go back is lost.

The **second approach** was to add dummy `Node` on creation, to model the beginning. It had an issue of determining if I'm at the beginning of the list, since with this approach I don't know where is the beginning until its too late.

```
    Iterator(Node root)
    {
        current = new Node(null, null, root);
    }

    public E next()
    {
        //checks and stuff
        current = current.getNext();
        return current.getValue();
    }
```

So, **question** is: is it possible to implement `ListIterator<>` only knowing the current element? If yes, some code scratches would be great.

**EDIT:**

`Node`:

```
private class Node
{
    private Node prev;
    private T value;
    private Node next;

    Node(Node prev, T value, Node next) {
        this.setPrev(prev);
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setNext(next);
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

`CustomLinkedList<E>`:

```
public class CustomLinkedList<T>  implements Iterable<T>{
    private class Node {/**/}

    private class Iterator implements java.util.ListIterator<T> {
        Node current;

        public Iterator(Node root) //from the first approach
        {
            current = root; 
        }

        //other methods
    }

    Node root;
    int size;

    //Object methods, and some basic Collection methods
}
```

Comment: Unless you have doubly linked nodes, there would be no way to go back, if you only know the current element. You would not be able to implement `previous`.

Comment: @JornVernee, they are double linked. I'll put the code of the node in the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @JoeC, I'm doing it for fun. It is not homework question. I'll include that as well

Comment: Btw, if you want to rapidly pass labs with stacks and queues, you could use the API's own [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)

Comment: @JornVernee, from what I've heard I can't use any libraries at all. But thanks, I'll consider it if that's not the case

Comment: `I'm doing it for fun. It is not homework question.`  &&  `from what I've heard I can't use any libraries at all.` ==  does not compute.

Comment: @dramzy, fair point. I could do this with arrays, but I would like to use my `CustomLinkedList`. I can't word it better, sorry. **edit**: I forgot that we don't need to implement `Iterable<E>` at all.

Comment: Can you post your `CustomLinkedList` code? Is `Node` a private inner class of `CustomLinkedList`?

Comment: You could always look at the existing implementation for inspiration: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr which keeps track of the previous node.

Comment: @dramzy, I will do it shortly. I will need to chop it down since it also implements some other interfaces.

Comment: @JornVernee, thanks! I didn't know the code is publicly available. I considered keeping track of the last node, but thought I'm just being dumb and not able to figure out better way.

Comment: @dramzy, I've added some pieces. I can put some more if needed. The post is getting too lengthy, which will probably decrease the chance of the question getting answered.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the problem is, can't you just call `current.getPrevious()`? And why do you need to pass `root`?

Comment: @dramzy, in the first approach it will lead to `NullPointerException`, since because of post increment the current will get to null eventually. With the second, `getPrevious()` will get out of bounds, since there is a dummy node at the beginning, and no way to figure out if it is dummy or not without doing two step check.

Comment: Why do you need the dummy node? Just start out with `current` being `root`. You're supposed to throw a `NoSuchElementException` when they call `next()` or `previous()` when `hasNext()` or `hasPrevious()` return false accordingly.

Comment: @dramzy, I guess I'll skip the first node then, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Incomputable, please check LinkedList implementation of standard JDK. I think it can help. I can't understand why do you need to create wheel if its already created!?

Comment: @eg04lt3r, I'm coming from C++ background and want to be library writer/maintainer by trade. So, I want to know how everything works. Non iterable version actually is already enough for my labs, but I found in-between concept to be very interesting compared to C++ iterators, which directly point to at some element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public class CustomLinkedList<T>  implements Iterable<T>{
    private class Node {/**/}

    private class Iterator implements ListIterator<T> {
        Node next, previous;

        Iterator() {
            next = root;
            previous = null; 
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }

        public T next() {
            if ( ! hasNext()){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            previous = next;
            next = next.getNext();
            return previous;
        }

        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return previous != null;
        }

        public T previous() {
            if ( ! hasPrevious() ){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            next = next.getPrevious();
            previous = next.getPrevious();
            return next;
        }
    }

    Node root;
    int size;

    //Object methods, and some basic Collection methods
}
```

This doesn't implement the other methods of the `ListIterator` interface, but you get the idea. You need to think of your iterator's cursor as being in-between the previous and the next element, not on one of them. For a proper implementation, see [Jorn Vernee's link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr).

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out, and I'll accept the answer once I get the tests passing.

Comment: I don't think this right yet, once you reach the end of the list, `next` becomes null and then you cannot do `previous()`, same with going too far backwards.

Comment: yeah, I felt that too. I tried this version, but couldn't go back using it.

Comment: I've just created the version with previous too :) seems like it is the only way to do it